# Ionic2 uncaught promise

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, ionic2

I am currently learning the ropes around Angular2 in Ionic2.
I am going through a tutorial that is a bit outdated, and since i'm not 100% familiar with Angular2 environments, I can't debug this error:

`Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for ReposPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents? Error: No component factory found for ReposPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents? at noComponentFactoryError`

**These are the files I've changed from a clean ionic2 install:**

#### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform, MenuController, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';

import { HelloIonicPage } from '../pages/hello-ionic/hello-ionic';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';

import { UsersPage } from '../pages/users/users';
import { ReposPage } from '../pages/repos/repos';
import { OrganisationsPage } from '../pages/organisations/organisations';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  // make HelloIonicPage the root (or first) page
  rootPage = HelloIonicPage;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public menu: MenuController,
    public statusBar: StatusBar,
    public splashScreen: SplashScreen
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // set our app's pages
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Users', component: UsersPage },
      { title: 'Repos', component: ReposPage },
      { title: 'Organisations', component: OrganisationsPage },
      { title: 'Hello Ionic', component: HelloIonicPage },
      { title: 'My First List', component: ListPage }
    ];
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // close the menu when clicking a link from the menu
    this.menu.close();
    // navigate to the new page if it is not the current page
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
}
```

#### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { HelloIonicPage } from '../pages/hello-ionic/hello-ionic';
import { ItemDetailsPage } from '../pages/item-details/item-details';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HelloIonicPage,
    ItemDetailsPage,
    ListPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HelloIonicPage,
    ItemDetailsPage,
    ListPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I have also created 3 pages through the `ionic g page` command.

## any help on this issue would be grateful.

Comment: the title of this question is misleading ... there's never anything that says  `uncaught promise`

Comment: this ionic 2 not 3 right? no lazy loading?

Comment: @suraj ionic2 out of the box, with cordova.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `ReposPage` in `ngModule` in **app.module.ts** .
It should be present in both declarations and entryComponents array.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HelloIonicPage,
    ItemDetailsPage,
    ListPage,
    ReposPage //here
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HelloIonicPage,
    ItemDetailsPage,
    ListPage,
    ReposPage //here
  ],
```

Answer (score 2):

as the error message clearly saying, you need to add 'ReposPage' to the entryComponents array in app.modules.ts file. Also you would need to add it as a declaration.

declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HelloIonicPage,
    ItemDetailsPage,
    ListPage,
ReposPage
  ]

entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HelloIonicPage,
    ItemDetailsPage,
    ListPage,
ReposPage
  ]

Comment: Literally the same answer as mine :P

Comment: meh.. simple enough problem